# Sublime text package for formatting/aligning variable declarations

Tags: sublime-text

In other words, I want to make this:

```
    $this->ml_seller_rep_table = $sm->get('Admin\Model\MercadoLibre\MercadoLibreSellerReputationFactory');
    $this->sat_entity_table = $sm->get('Admin\Model\SAT\SatEntityFactory');
    $this->sat_invoice_table = $sm->get('Admin\Model\SAT\SatInvoiceFactory');
    $this->sat_invoice_item_table = $sm->get('Admin\Model\SAT\SatInvoiceItemFactory');
```

Into this

```
    $this->ml_seller_rep_table      = $sm->get('Admin\Model\MercadoLibre\MercadoLibreSellerReputationFactory');
    $this->sat_entity_table             = $sm->get('Admin\Model\SAT\SatEntityFactory');
    $this->sat_invoice_table            = $sm->get('Admin\Model\SAT\SatInvoiceFactory');
    $this->awsFileTypeTable             = $sm->get('Admin\Model\Aws\AwsFileTypeFactory');
```

Basically, to standardise the variable declarations by selecting the text and re-indent it with a single key-binding for legibility purposes.

Any ideas of a tool that already does this? This package must be compatible with Sublime Text version 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Sublime Alignment Package](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Alignment). You only then have to configure the alignment characters you want Sublime Text to recognise. See [here](http://www.granneman.com/webdev/editors/sublime-text/packages/how-to-install-and-use-sublime-alignment/) for a tutorial on how to do that.

Comment: Works like a charm